# What is the best way to remove hair from carpets?

Tags: cleaning, carpet

We do have a vacuum cleaner, but unfortunately that does not do a good job.

I do not mind purchasing a new one, but I am going to be here only for the next 3 - 6 months and I would rather not buy one unless absolutely necessary.

I found the following while searching if someone had already answered

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/removing-hair-carpet-48919.html

It does a partially better job than the vacuum, but does not remove most of them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I know you said you don't want to buy a vacuum if you don't have to, but I've been happy with our [Dyson Animal DC50](http://www.dyson.com/vacuums/uprights/dc50/dc50-animal.aspx) -- it does a great job with removing pet hair from carpets. Of course, it's pretty expensive, for a cheaper option, Consumer Reports liked the $99 [Hoover Windtunnel T Series Rewind bagless](http://hoover.com/products/details/uh70120/t-series-windtunnel-rewind-plus-bagless-upright/) and gave it high ratings for pet hair removal. I'm not sure if good pet hair removal performance translates well to removing human hair.

Comment: Vacuum cleaners are portable, you can probably take it with you when you leave? Or by "*I am going to be here only for the next 3 - 6 months*", do you mean you'll only be on Earth for the next 3-6 months?

Comment: @Tester101, probably traveling from one country to another... different plugs, power supplies, etc... ?

Answer (score 1):

For problem areas, I tape together a square of masking tape about a foot (0.3 meters) on a side, and press that onto the carpet after a stiff brushing. The sticky will pull the hair right out. It'd be a ***lot*** of work for large areas though.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not mind purchasing a new one

Ok, if you don't mind purchasing a new one then I can offer you my experience. We had a dog for about a year that had long white hair. And, it shed hair everywhere. It wasn't so bad getting it up on the hardwood floors and tile, but, it loved to lay on the rugs. Well, we had a couple of inexpensive Hoover or Dirt Devil or whatever vacuums that we used for awhile (another story), but they wouldn't pick up all of the hair. But, our old Kenmore cannister vacuum with the beater brush took it right up. So, I think you need a vacuum with a beater brush. It vibrates the carpet, loosening the hair, and sucks it right up. They are probably still a lot more expensive than the inexpensive ones, but, we've had the Kenmore for about 30 years. I've done some minor repairs to it over the years, but nothing major. And Sears has always had the parts I needed. Think of it as a long-term investment.

Answer (score 0):

I have this [carpet rake](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Roberts-Carpet-Groomer-and-Rug-Rake-with-12-in-Wide-Head-70-125/100658262) and it helps loosen and pick up hair as well as reviving the texture of the carpet. Helps bring up other dust and debris that are too far down for the vacuum cleaner to get on it's own. I have a good canister vac with a beater brush but the carpet rake helps it do a better job.

Takes a little manual effort but helps your carpets and it keeps the beater brush of the vac from getting all clogged up with hair. Even a cheaper upright I had years ago did a decent enough job but the hair cept getting caught in the beater brush and I'd wind up burning through belts fast.

Answer (score -1):

Contact paper! You know the rolls we used cover books with. I imagine it would be perfect for lifting hair